# Sort array of objects based on object property that has special chars

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, like this:

`array = [ {userId: 'Y-10'}, {userId: 'Y-1'}, {userId: 'Y-14'}, {userId: 'Y-24'} ];`

I need to sort the array by the `userId` in order. The results should be in this order: 'Y-1','Y-10','Y-14','Y-24'

I tried using a sort like this `array.sort((a,b) => ("" + a.userId).localeCompare(b.userId, undefined, {numeric: true}));`

But this doesnt work. How can I sort my array to yield the results i'm seeking?

Comment: I tried the one liner, my version of objs.sort((a,b) => (a.last_nom > b.last_nom) ? 1 : ((b.last_nom > a.last_nom) ? -1 : 0))
but this does not work. I think the "-" is throwing it off...

Comment: `(a,b) => +s1.match(/\d+/) > +b.match(/\d+/)` might work?

Comment: Objs.sort((a,b)=>{parseInt(a.userId.split(‘-‘)[1]) - parseInt(b.userId.split(‘-‘)[1])});

Comment: That does not work Peter. For example, I get "Y-9" after "Y-2"

Comment: Hey try this

`const array = [{ userId: 'Y-10' }, { userId: 'Y-1' }, { userId: 'Y-14' }, { userId: 'Y-24' }];


const compare = (a, b) => {
    const num_a = +a.userId.split('-')[1];
    const num_b = +b.userId.split('-')[1];
    console.log("pppp ", num_a);
    if (num_a < num_b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (num_a > num_b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
console.log(array.sort(compare));`

Comment: @Pd1234 Y-9 should come after Y-2 if you want  Y-1 to come before Y-10. --- Please clarify the outputs you want.

Comment: @Barty may you post an answer rather than posting large amounts of code in comments?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, I meant "Y-9" comes before "Y-2".

Comment: @PD1234 looks good to me
`let array = [{ userId: 'Y-10' }, { userId: 'Y-1' }, { userId: 'Y-14' }, { userId: 'Y-24' }];

array = array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.userId.split('-')[1]) - parseInt(b.userId.split('-')[1]));
console.log(array); `

[ { userId: 'Y-1' },
  { userId: 'Y-10' },
  { userId: 'Y-14' },
  { userId: 'Y-24' } ]


[ { userId: 'Y-1' },
  { userId: 'Y-2' },
  { userId: 'Y-9' },
  { userId: 'Y-10' },
  { userId: 'Y-14' },
  { userId: 'Y-24' } ]

Comment: There were two outputs in that block and one had the 2 and the 9 in there. the sort function returns an array which you should assign back to the original array or a new one.